# Converse of the Sobolev Theorem

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, closed-graph

I am trying to solve the following problem (9.33 in Folland's book).

If $H^s \subset C_0^k$, then $s>k+\frac{n}{2}$.

The hint suggests to use the closed graph theorem in order to show that the inclusion map $H^s \rightarrow C_0^k$ is continuous and hence that $\partial^{\alpha}\delta \in (H^s)^{*}$ for $|\alpha| \leq k$.

I tried to argue using sequences but I was not able to do it properly.

Can anyone help me?